# PostFix Issue When Sending Emails through Outlook

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, email-client

I also have the Relay access denied issue and it's really disturbing me. 
I can send and receive normally from the web mail.

However, when I configure the email on [B]Outlook [/B]without using Authentication for Outgoing emails am getting the below error:

> Error: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[MyIPaddress]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=

If I do use My Outgoing server requires Authentication, I get:

> Log onto incoming mail server (POP3): Your e-mail server rejected your login with Secure Password Authentication (SPA). Verify the account properties in Account Settings. Send test e-mail message: None of the authentication methods supported by this client are supported by your server.

mail_version = 2.6.6

main.cf:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_interfaces = all

# Enable IPv4, and IPv6 if supported
inet_protocols = all

mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, testing, testing.domain.com

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550



#alias_maps = dbm:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
#alias_maps = netinfo:/aliases

# The alias_database parameter specifies the alias database(s) that
# are built with "newaliases" or "sendmail -bi".  This is a separate
# configuration parameter, because alias_maps (see above) may specify
# tables that are not necessarily all under control by Postfix.
#
#alias_database = dbm:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = dbm:/etc/mail/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/opt/majordomo/aliases

# ADDRESS EXTENSIONS (e.g., user+foo)
#
# The recipient_delimiter parameter specifies the separator between
# user names and address extensions (user+foo). See canonical(5),
# local(8), relocated(5) and virtual(5) for the effects this has on
# aliases, canonical, virtual, relocated and .forward file lookups.
# Basically, the software tries user+foo and .forward+foo before
# trying user and .forward.
#
#recipient_delimiter = +


debug_peer_level = 2

# The debug_peer_list parameter specifies an optional list of domain
# or network patterns, /file/name patterns or type:name tables. When
# an SMTP client or server host name or address matches a pattern,
# increase the verbose logging level by the amount specified in the
# debug_peer_level parameter.
#
#debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
#debug_peer_list = some.domain

# The debugger_command specifies the external command that is executed
# when a Postfix daemon program is run with the -D option.
#
# Use "command .. & sleep 5" so that the debugger can attach before
# the process marches on. If you use an X-based debugger, be sure to
# set up your XAUTHORITY environment variable before starting Postfix.
#
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

# If you can't use X, use this to capture the call stack when a
# daemon crashes. The result is in a file in the configuration
# directory, and is named after the process name and the process ID.
#
# debugger_command =
#   PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin; export PATH; (echo cont;
#   echo where) | gdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id 2>&1
#   >$config_directory/$process_name.$process_id.log & sleep 5
#
# Another possibility is to run gdb under a detached screen session.
# To attach to the screen sesssion, su root and run "screen -r
# <id_string>" where <id_string> uniquely matches one of the detached
# sessions (from "screen -list").
#
# debugger_command =
#   PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin; export PATH; screen
#   -dmS $process_name gdb $daemon_directory/$process_name
#   $process_id & sleep 1

# INSTALL-TIME CONFIGURATION INFORMATION
#
# The following parameters are used when installing a new Postfix version.
# 
# sendmail_path: The full pathname of the Postfix sendmail command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible mail posting interface.
# 
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix

# newaliases_path: The full pathname of the Postfix newaliases command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible command to build alias databases.
#
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix

# mailq_path: The full pathname of the Postfix mailq command.  This
# is the Sendmail-compatible mail queue listing command.
# 
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

# setgid_group: The group for mail submission and queue management
# commands.  This must be a group name with a numerical group ID that
# is not shared with other accounts, not even with the Postfix account.
#
setgid_group = postdrop

# html_directory: The location of the Postfix HTML documentation.
#
html_directory = no

# manpage_directory: The location of the Postfix on-line manual pages.
#
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

# sample_directory: The location of the Postfix sample configuration files.
# This parameter is obsolete as of Postfix 2.1.
#
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples

# readme_directory: The location of the Postfix README files.
#
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
mailbox_size_limit = 0
allow_percent_hack = no
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I actually configured TLS and added the below to main.cf

smtpd_enforce_tls                = no
smtpd_tls_loglevel               = 1
smtpd_use_tls                    = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file               = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file              = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert

Then I unchecked Require Logon using SPA and it worked perfectly :)